# Count to how many categories a post belongs to

Tags: posts, categories, count

Is there a possibility to count to how many categories a post belongs to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `get_the_terms()` and count the resulting array:

```
print count( get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'category' ) ) . ' categories';
```